# Override a RelativeLayout's onMeasure() to constrain its aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have an extended `RelativeLayout` which, when programmatically positioned and sized using `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, needs to restrict itself to a given aspect ratio. Typically, I would wish for it to constrain itself to 1:1, so that if the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` contain a `width` of 200 and a `height` of 100, the custom `RelativeLayout` would constrain itself to 100 x 100.

I am already used to overriding `onMeasure()` in ordinary custom `View`s in order to achieve similar aims. For example, I have created my own SVG image converter, and the custom `View` that renders the SVG image has an overridden `onMeasure()` that ensures that the call to `setMeasuredDimension()` contains dimensions that (a) fit within the original measurement specifications, and (b) match the aspect ratio of the original SVG image.

Going back to my custom `RelativeLayout` which I wish to constrain itself in a similar way, I've tried overriding `onMeasure()` but I haven't had much success. Knowing that `RelativeLayout`'s `onMeasure()` performs all of the child `View` placement, what I'm generally trying to do at the moment, but without the desired results, is to override `onMeasure()` such that I initially modify the dimension specifications first (i.e. apply my desired constraints) and then call `super.onMeasure()`. Like this:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){

    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);      
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    // Restrict the aspect ratio to 1:1, fitting within original specified dimensions
    int chosenDimension = Math.min(chosenWidth, chosenHeight);
    widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(chosenDimension, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(chosenDimension, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

What *actually* happens when I do this is that, bizarrely, the height is properly restricted as I intended, but the width is not. To illustrate:

- Specifying a height of 200 and width of 100 in the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` results in my custom `RelativeLayout` having a height of 100 and width of 100. -> Correct.
- Specifying a height of 100 and width of 200 in the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` results in my custom `RelativeLayout` having a height of 100 and width of 200. -> Not correct.

I realise that I could instead apply my aspect ratio constraint logic within the calling class that's placing the `RelativeLayout` in the first place (and in the meantime I may well do that to get around this), but really this is an implementation detail that I want the `RelativeLayout` itself to perform.

Clarification: The resultant width and height values I'm reading back are from using `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`. These values are read back some time in the future, after the layout process has been performed again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have got around this now by also setting the `width` and `height` of the `LayoutParams` currently held by the `RelativeLayout` in the `onMeasure()`.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure (int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){

    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);      
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    // Restrict the aspect ratio to 1:1, fitting within original specified dimensions
    int chosenDimension = Math.min(widthSize, heightSize);
    widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(chosenDimension, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(chosenDimension, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);

    getLayoutParams().height = chosenDimension;
    getLayoutParams().width = chosenDimension;
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);    
    }
```

This now works as desired: The size of the `RelativeLayout` (and subsequent calls to `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`) now agree with size restrictions applied in my overridden `onMeasure()`.